# How to dynamically update dates in SpotfireTitles

Tags: r, spotfire

I would like to avoid having to manually change the dates in the title of a Spotfire dashboard every week. The goal is to get every Sunday's date in short format: so in the case of this week, the title would read "As of 1/14/2018".
I tried to link the expression in the title to the below R script to no avail:

```
d <-  as.Date( Sys.Date() ) 
prev.days <- seq( d - 6, d ,by = 'day' )

Sunday <- prev.days[weekdays(prev.days) =='Sunday']
```

The chunk of code above is linked to a Document Property called Sundays. When I try to insert the document property in the title as such 'As of ${Sundays}', Spotfire detects a conversion issue:

> "Error in FUN(X[[i]]) : inherits(funValue, "POSIXct") is not TRUE'.

I also tried forcing a conversion by using `as.POSIXct()` in the script to no avail. I would like to avoid using R packages like lubridate as they seem buggy when used in tandem with Spotfire.

Finally, if you know a way to bypass R and write a code in Spotfire's native language that would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just gave your script a try with one small edit (added as.POSIXct)

```
d <-  as.Date( Sys.Date() ) 
prev.days <- seq( d - 6, d ,by = 'day' )

Sunday <- as.POSIXct(prev.days[weekdays(prev.days) =='Sunday'])
```

I set Sunday as an output parameter to a DocumentProperty, and then added the DocumentProperty to the title bar. All displayed as expected, e.g. "01/21/2018 07:00:00" in DateTime format. As I understand it, TERR will always send results as type DateTime format.

Without the as.POSIXct conversion, TERR passes the value to Spotfire as Real.

Go here for more details on TERR and DateTime: https://support.tibco.com/s/article/What-TERR-object-class-does-the-Spotfire-data-function-framework-recognize-as-date-time-information?_ga=2.117439810.555218220.1516612347-1562366391.1506414681